# Including excluded jars in intellij run configurations

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, intellij-idea, jar

I have a hadoop job that gets deployed to Amazon EMR. Because EMR provides a `hadoop-core` jar, I've configured the dependency in my `pom` as `provided`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.2-cdh3u6</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

The problem is that when I want to debug the jar within intellij, it can't find one of the classes in this jar, `org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar`.

Is it possible to configure Intellij to include this jar on the classpath when debugging/running the jar within intellij, but still to exclude this jar from the output jar?

The path to the actual jar on my local machine is `/Users/jbrown/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-cdh3u6/hadoop-core-0.20.2-cdh3u6.jar` - I've tried adding `-cp /Users/jbrown/.m2/repository/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/0.20.2-cdh3u6/hadoop-core-0.20.2-cdh3u6.jar` to the VM options in the run config, but then the job couldn't run at all.

Comment: Assuming...Maven? If so, please clarify for users who may have an answer. Also consider revising you referral to each JAR with consistent naming conventions to make it easier for users to understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using maven from your dependency example, you can use multiple maven profiles to tackle this problem.

You can have a `prod` and `debug` profiles which include a `dependencies` section. The debug one can skip the `provided` tag for all hadoop related dependencies, which would include the dependencies in the final JAR.

You can read more about maven profiles [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html).

Comment: @jbrown. Please upvote the answer if you feel the suggestion can solve your problem. Thanks! Happy hadooping!